# attach() working from tinker but not controller

Tags: php, laravel

I want to implement a many to many relationship on the same class. Course has pre-requisite courses. Attach works from tinker but not from a controller.

```
$course->pre_reqs()->attach(int); // works from tinker

//does not work from controller (I checked that $course is the right object)
$course =  DB::table('courses')->where('id', $id1)->first();
$course->pre_reqs()->attach(10);

//from model
public function pre_reqs()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Course', 'pre_req', 'course_id', 'pre_req_course_id' );
}
```

The pivot table works with tinker.

The error is

> call to undefined method pre_reqs

Comment: Isn't it only a typo? notice how "in tinker" you are doing things around - attach first and then your pre_reqs function, but in controller you call firstly pre_reqs() and then attach.

Comment: that was a typo in the post. It's now correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give a try with Model Class

```
$course =  Course::where('id', $id1)->first();
$course->pre_reqs()->attach(10);
```